# Py3 imaplib: get only immediate body (no reply) of email

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, imaplib

I'm using python3 and imaplib to retrieve emails from an inbox, so far so good. But these emails are part of a reply chain, and the part payload I get includes the message I reply to as well as the original email content. Is there a way to get only the original content (i.e. if you were viewing the email in gmail's web client, the part of the email before you click `...` to view its context)?

```
import email
import imaplib

mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
mail.login("xxx@gmail.com", "xxx")
mail.select('inbox')
result, data = mail.search(None, "UNSEEN") # (ALL/UNSEEN)

i = len(data[0].split())
if i > 1:
    print("More than one unread email! Using last one.")
if i == 0:
    print("No unread emails. Will check again soon.")
else:
    result, msg = mail.fetch(data[0].split()[i-1], "(RFC822)")
    msg = email.message_from_bytes(msg[0][1])
    #if msg.is_multipart():
    #   for payload in msg.get_payload():
    #       print(payload.get_payload())
    maintype = msg.get_content_maintype()
    if maintype == "multipart":
        for part in msg.get_payload():
            if part.get_content_maintype() == "text":
                print(part.get_payload())
    elif maintype == "text":
        print(part.get_payload())
```

This is what I get:

```
Again reply!

On Mon, Aug 14, 2017 at 6:34 PM, <xxx@gmail.com> wrote:

> Test message
>

<div dir=3D"ltr">Again reply!</div><div class=3D"gmail_extra"><br><div clas=
s=3D"gmail_quote">On Mon, Aug 14, 2017 at 6:34 PM,  <span dir=3D"ltr">&lt;<=
a href=3D"mailto:xxx@gmail.com" target=3D"_blank">xxx@gmail.com=
</a>&gt;</span> wrote:<br><blockquote class=3D"gmail_quote" style=3D"margin=
:0 0 0 .8ex;border-left:1px #ccc solid;padding-left:1ex">Test message<br>
</blockquote></div><br></div>
```

Comment: In one of the answers to that question they mention a potentially useful library, [quotequail](https://github.com/closeio/quotequail)

Comment: I think that question summarizes it nicely, thanks.